# Using OpenID (gmail) to authenticate a user to a drupal site

Tags: drupal, authentication, openid, gmail, google-openid

I want to develop a Drupal site, where I want to provide the user with a login screen. The user will be authenticated if they enter a valid gmail username/password, and will be taken to the main page from there. I believe I can use OpenID for this, but I am kind of lost on the specifics of how to use it. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for http://drupal.org/project/rpx.